# How can I make the link to the middle of page in symfony2 and twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

One question for link generator of symfony2

I am making link like this

```
<a href="{{ path('acme_link',{'user':'taro') }} ">click!</a>
```

it publishes link like this below.

```
<a href=".../move/taro">click!</a>
```

But I want to make the link to the middle of page such as

```
<a href=".../move/taro#middle">click!!</a>
```

How can I do that by Symfony link generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the link and then add `#middle` to it:

```
<a href="{{ path('acme_link', {'user':'taro'}) }}#middle">click!</a>
```